# ¿Como crear bien un arreglo?

Tags: javascript, sheetjs

hola muy buenas tardes a todos espero este disfrutando este domingo,
estoy usando sheetjs para crear documentos en mi proyecto pero nose hacer que mi arreglo tenga "saltos de linea?"o bueno que se vea de esta manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
*imagen 1*

siento que tengo la solucion pero no me acuerdo como hacerlo la verdad aun sigo buscando ya que mi arreglo que estoy creando me lo hace de esta otra manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*imagen 2*

```
var $data = [
        ["esto es una prueba"],
        ["S", "h", "e", "e", "t", "J"],
        $datos_ingresos_doc
    ];
    /* este es el codigo que llevo haciendo y me da el resultado de la imagen 2 */
    var ws_data = $data;
    console.log(ws_data);

    /*Asi es como estoy llenando los datos a la variable*/
    $(response.Ingresos).each(function(i, item) {
                $datos_ingresos_doc[i] = [item.fecha, parseInt(item.cantidades)];
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazlo así mejor, usando el método [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) directamente sobre `$data`:

```js
Ingresos = [{fecha: "2022-10-23",cantidades: 3},{fecha: "2022-10-24",cantidades: 4}]
var $data = [
  ["esto es una prueba"],
  ["S", "h", "e", "e", "t", "J"]
]
$(Ingresos).each(function(i, item) {
  $data.push([item.fecha, parseInt(item.cantidades)]);
})
console.log($data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Eres una pistola amigo muchas gracias me funciono a la perfección un saludo y ten un feliz domingo